# Error while trying to install python modules using pip

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I'm getting these warning and errors

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pygame/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pygame/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pygame
```

whenever I try to install python module in terminal.

This is the error cmd is throwing whenever trying to install any module:

[image]

Kindly help me solving the error or suggest me if there is any other way to install python modules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], then read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: `random` is [part of Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#module-random). There is no need to `pip install` it (nor will that work, e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46868526/354577) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68582382/354577)). Why do you think you need to do this?